# Bruteforce different encodings

Tags: hash, brute-force, hashcat

I have a hash

```
$office$*2013*100000*256*16*664f9e0787392c2b1632d3947aaadee4*27dc7d029f76244a407acf9b5afa3740*ebbc055ae08124f6a6be81ef812da4fece16b2ad86eede3916d9cda15f71833f
```

password: лl

My wordlist:

```
6ceb
eb6c
6c6c
лл
лl
ll
```

Start hashcat

```
hashcat -a 0 -m 9600 'h.lst' 'wordlist.txt'  --force
```

this leads to failure. 
As I understand it, the problem is in different encodings, I tried using hex instead of regular passwords. It did not help. Tell me, is it possible to use a hashcat with different languages? If not, it turns out that such a password cannot be cracked?

output hashcat

```
Session..........: hashcat                       
Status...........: Exhausted
Hash.Type........: MS Office 2013
Hash.Target......: $office$*2013*100000*256*16*664f9e0787392c2b1632d39...71833f
Time.Started.....: Tue Mar 24 14:43:55 2020 (2 secs)
Time.Estimated...: Tue Mar 24 14:43:57 2020 (0 secs)
Guess.Base.......: File (/root/Рабочий стол/pass/1/1)
Guess.Queue......: 1/1 (100.00%)
Speed.#1.........:        5 H/s (0.21ms) @ Accel:128 Loops:32 Thr:1 Vec:8
Recovered........: 0/1 (0.00%) Digests, 0/1 (0.00%) Salts
Progress.........: 8/8 (100.00%)
Rejected.........: 0/8 (0.00%)
Restore.Point....: 8/8 (100.00%)
Restore.Sub.#1...: Salt:0 Amplifier:0-1 Iteration:99968-100000
Candidates.#1....: $HEX[6ceb] -> $HEX[55]
```

Comment: "I tried using hex" -- do you mean `--hex-charset`? Because that's the answer. If so, then you need to explain "it did not help". What command did you run? What was the output?

Comment: I used  --hex-wordlist .

Comment: I  tried --hex-charset. Hashcat did not crack password